# How to make a while loop circular java

Tags: java, circular-list

This is a DuckDuckGoose problem. The last while loop is not circular list. How do you make it circular so that it can remove and then goes next then moves on to the others segment of list to the next random number in the list. I have to use iterator class with no indexes.  Because `iterator.hasNext()` only goes up to the end of the list and not circular. How do I make the while loop make the list circular and end up with one winner?

19 names

http://collabedit.com/q248e

```
public class DuckDuckGoose {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<String> linkedlist = new LinkedList<String>();
        // add try catch to add list
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\src\\players.txt");
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fr);

            while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                linkedlist.add(inFile.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Iterator<String> iterator = linkedlist.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            // random number Goose landed method
            if (getRandomBoolean()) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(linkedlist);
    }

    public static boolean getRandomBoolean() {
        return Math.random() < .80;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a while loop on top of your while loop:

```
while(linkedlist.size() > 1){
    iterator = linkedlist.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        // random number Goose landed method
        if (getRandomBoolean()) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
        if(linkedlist.size() == 1) break;
    }    
}
```

Now notice that I added a `break` statement inside your original loop. This is to make sure we always stop when your list contains 1 player and not when it's empty.

To explain it, imagine we didn't have that `break` statement and you start the inner while loop with two players, `player1` and `player2`.
`getRandomBoolean()` returns true, `player1` is removed
`getRandomBoolean()` returns true again, `player2` is removed.
Both `while` loops stop, but your list is now empty.

Comment: Thanks. I do not know if it is my computer but the output does not show most of the time.

Comment: That's weird, try to see with the debugger if the linkedlist is not empty, normally it shouldn't

Comment: It works but I am not randomly getting a different name. How do you get a random name as the winner (last)?

Comment: How many times have you run it? I get a lot of "Scooby" but's that normal because he is the less likely to be eliminated since he is the last, but try to run it like 10 times or change your condition to another value, like 0.4

Comment: I did 0.4 but it still does not work. I think there might have to be another while loop to random the linked list above the first one linked.size() ?

Comment: No need to randomize more, I ran that exact code and I have no issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    List<String> players = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("c:/Users/src/players.txt"));
    String winner = getWinner(players);
    System.out.println("winner is " + winner);
}

public static String getWinner(List<String> players) {
    players = new ArrayList<>(players);
    Iterator<String> it = players.iterator();
    Random random = new Random();

    while (players.size() > 1) {
        (it = it.hasNext() ? it : players.iterator()).next();

        if (random.nextBoolean())
            it.remove();
    }

    return players.iterator().next();
}
```